# Installer and Updater for a python desktop application

Tags: python, windows, nsis, auto-update, pyinstaller

I am building a desktop app with python and packaging it to an exe with Pyinstaller.
I would like to ship my application with an installer and also provide automatic and silent updates to the software like Google Chrome, Dropbox or Github for Windows does.

I have found the following software to be able to do this:

- [Google Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/) - Does not provide a server
- [Github Shimmer](https://github.com/github/Shimmer) - The perfect solution but Paul told me it can't handle non .Net apps yet
- [WinSparkle](http://winsparkle.org/) - Updater only.
- [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) - As the name suggests very .Net focused
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) - Installer.
- [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.80).aspx) - .NET only

I am trying to find the easiest solution to my problem.

Comment: What prevents you from packaging WinSparkle into an InnoSetup, NSIS or WiX installer?

Comment: WinSparkle seems to always ask if the update should be installed. I just want it to update.

Comment: How is this not a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)?

Comment: I will try and rephrase the question to be less like a shopping question. @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a suite of tools from the cloudmatrix guys that addresses that problem.

[esky](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky) is an auto-update framework for frozen apps that is compatible with the common python "packaging" frameworks. [signedimp](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/signedimp/0.3.2) tries to ensure that apps are not modified after they are signed, and to minimize invasive Windows UAC dialogs. [myppy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/myppy/0.1.0) aims to insulate you from base library incompatibility issues on Linux eg installing on distributions with different gcc and libc versions. The whole set can be seen on github [here](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/).

The video and slides from this year's PyCon are here: http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spckh/

Comment: Thank you. We are now using esky and contributing to the project aswell :) Plus it also works on mac.

Answer (score 7):

[WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) (Windows Installer XML toolset) is an open source project for an MSI authoring tool.
Part of the project is [ClickThrough](http://wix.sourceforge.net/ctvision.html), a set of add-on tools, including a tool to automatically detect available updates (via an RSS feed), notify users and install the update.
As you can read [here](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm#WiX):

> The Windows Installer Xml (WiX) toolset is composed of a compiler, a
>   linker, a lib tool and a decompiler. It generates MSI and MSM files
>   from XML input. It doesn't include a GUI frontend to create the
>   project files, but there are a couple of projects that plan to fill
>   this gap. Votive, which is part of the WiX project, is a Visual Studio
>   extension. It allows you to create "WiX projects" that act like any
>   other project in a VS solution.  WiX was created by Rob Mensching, a
>   Microsoft employee and former member of the MSI team, in his free time
>   and released as open source. It is used by several teams inside
>   Microsoft to create their setups.

See also [How to create a simple MSI installer using WIX](http://themech.net/2008/08/how-to-create-a-simple-msi-installer-using-wix/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a project that you may find useful.

[PyUpdater](https://www.github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Google Omaha.  You can get managed servers for pretty cheap now days if the only thing holding you back is the server / overhead cost.

Comment: By the server is not included I am talking about the software to distribute the files. That as far as I understand has to be built to specification.