# Python Pyinstaller - How to Patch Program That I Have Built?

Tags: python, patch, pyinstaller

I have built a keyword search tool in Python, and then converted it into an *.exe* format with Pyinstaller, so people at my workplace could use it without having to install Python.

I have sent this around to everyone by e-mail in a RAR file which they have then saved to their desktops.

I am thinking of some potential tweaks I might make to it, but I do not want to have to keep on sending them the full program every time I decide I want to change something.

So, the question is, is there a way that I can send a patch file to upgrade the program instead?  What should I be looking at?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not easily. Whatever you send them is probably as complicated as overwriting the original installation. However, if your company has an internal website for hosting internally produced software, you might consider managing an internal download website, and start version control *now* while your distribution is probably still manageable.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. I presume they will still have to download the program every time I update it, or are you thinking of something more fancy i.e. I should design it so they access the program from the internal website?

Comment: You can get as fancy as you like. You can even have the program check for later versions on startup, display a dialog to the user if one exists, and then pull automatically and install if they say 'yes'. And you would probably use web services to facilitate the communication with a web server (to check for versions, initiate downloads, etc). Unless you are planning to distribute the software beyond your company, then hosting it internally should suffice.

Comment: Great, thank you Ron. I will do some googling to see how I can do that. It will only ever be internal.