# Update existing PyInstaller Package

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, build, pyinstaller

I have a working [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) package build for Windows which I would like to edit.

Our open source project releases a new version every two weeks, and I would like to automate the process using a single Linux server to generate packages for Linux, OS X, and Windows. Since the changes to the program are minor each week, and because cross compiling is not supported by PyInstaller I would like to update the python files in my existing working PyInstaller package instead of running a new build. From reading [the Docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4/advanced-topics.html) it looks to me like this should be possible, but I am unclear on how exactly I could reach in and edit my python files once PyInstaller has zipped them up. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44810175

Answer (score 1):

This is not so simple. The [docs you linked](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4/advanced-topics.html#python-imports-in-a-bundled-app) say that "PyInstaller embeds compiled python code (.pyc files) within the executable."

This means that the compilation process goes something like this:

1. Python compiles your .py files into bytecode, and saves it as .pyc files.
2. PyInstaller takes all of the .pyc file bytecode and puts it inside the .exe file.

So if you want to update the build without running PyInstaller again, you would need to replace the bytecode inside the .exe file. That sounds complicated and error-prone to me.

Instead, why not do something like install Windows in a virtual machine on your Linux server and run PyInstaller there?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion of an alternative. I will look into that option.

Comment: @BarSmith By the way, there are plenty of tools out there for setting up virtual machine builds and things like that. Searching for "cross-platform continuous delivery pipeline" should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what the OP is looking for, the approach described in the docs for [bundling-to-one-folder](https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder) may be useful in some cases:

> Another advantage of a one-folder bundle is that when you change your code, as long as it imports *exactly the same set of dependencies*, you could send out only the updated `myscript` executable. That is typically much smaller than the entire folder. ...

Also note the last remark from that paragraph is in line with [Jack Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350200):

> ... (If you change the script so that it imports more or different dependencies, or if the dependencies are upgraded, you must redistribute the whole bundle.)

If you do need to automate the build for different platforms, something like [GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) could be convenient. Examples can be found in this feature request: [pyinstaller/issues/6296](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6296).