# Push updates to python desktop apps

Tags: python, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm working in a small CG animation company that does need small tools for production and CG artists. I'm coming from an animator's background, so my knowledge of code is extremely basic, but I'm learning.

Here is the situation: I write python tools, most are using PySide for GUI. Now I need to regularly and easily deploy tools and updates to the machines in our studio (about 20 computers).

We do want to do things the right way and are willing to learn, but the amount of information is quite overwhelming for I am a neophyte.

I keep reading about various scary keywords that seem to be the answer I'm looking for, such as *DevOps*, *CI/CD*, *Docker*, *Kubernetes*...

We are setting up a Gitlab instance on our local server, and now I'm asking what would be the most suitable way to easily deploy my scripts and their requested environment easily onto the company's computers (MacOs, Windows, and Linux), and how should I package them.

I hope my question isn't vague but if so, please tell me and I'll try to be more precise.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I am following the [VFX industry standards](http://www.vfxplatform.com) so python 2.7 it is. And thanks, I'll have a close look at wheel (although your link doesn't seem right)

Comment: DevOps, CI/CD, Docker, Kubernetes.. are mainly used to automate deployment on servers (web apps). so it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry about that! I made a clipboard blunder. :oops: You'll find wheel [here](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20617997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyupdater seems to do just what you're trying to do.
have a look at [pyupdater.org](http://pyupdater.org) and [this demo](http://pyupdater-wx-demo.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: More options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20617997