# Python program distribution and updating methods

Tags: python, selenium, self-updating

I have created a python program that I want to share with other, less computer savvy, coworkers that do not have python on their computers.  I have been using pyinstaller to create a onefile exe and place it on a network drive for each person to copy to their own computers.  It usually runs fine but I continuously update the program to add more functionality.  As I update the code I have to recreate the exe, and tell each person to copy the new exe to their computer.  Is there an easier way to do this?

I have tried researching the two ideas below but I'm not sure if either of these are possible.

1. Is there a way to host this program on a website where each person could go to the website to run it?
2. Is there a way to push updates to the exe file that is already on their computers? (pyupdater seems to be the most popular but I don't see if I can push this to other computers)

If there is another option I am unaware of please let me know.  Not looking for a full 'how to' but rather is it possible and if so where should I be researching?

The program is a web scraper using Selenium with chromedriver on Windows 10 Python 3.7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617997/auto-updating-a-python-executable-generated-with-pyinstaller

Comment: For 1, look into Django/Flask to learn how to serve your program as a website. You'll likely need to learn *some* HTML/CSS/JavaScript, but there are tons of tutorials out there. You could serve it over LAN so that everyone connected to the network are able to access it through a web browser.

Comment: @jfaccioni I started looking into Django but I couldn't find if it was even possible to host a web scraping program.  Your comment makes me think it is possible so I will continue moving forward with the Django research.  Thanks