# How to update an py made exe file from my pc to people I have sent it to?

Tags: python, tkinter, server, pyinstaller, pygame-surface

What I mean is that I have a py file which I have converted to an exe file. So I wanted to know in case I decide to update the py file then how do I make it if I have sent it to someone the same changes occur in his file as well whether the exe or py file.

Answer (score 3):

Just send them the new exe file. But if you expect updates to be performed regularly consider adding the auto-update logic to your program using the [PyUpdater](https://www.pyupdater.org/) library

[Auto updating a python executable generated with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617997/auto-updating-a-python-executable-generated-with-pyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

Put your version of the program on a file share, or make it otherwise available in the internet and build in an update check in the program. So that it checks the URL for a new version everytime it is started.
I guess this is the most common way to do something like that.