# What to do with python extensions created by pyinstaller when a new version of a package is available?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pytube

I don't know if this question is asked before, but I couldn't find anything similar. Some python site packages (i.e. pytube) are updated fairly often and the old versions become non-functional. updating them is no problem, but what can I do when pyinstaller is used to create applications other than re-running pyinstaller on the scripts which is not possible since the client may not have python installed. Since the application is not `onefile` type, can I update the package just by changing some of the python extensions in the dist folder created by pyinstaller and how to get those extensions? Thank you!

Comment: Why not create updated versions of your file so that the users can download latest versions of it?

Comment: @Swagrim the main file is huge. Besides won't an Auto-Update application be more fun?

Comment: What if distribute the file once again (but the last time) by creating you executable file using py2exe? Then you can use esky to auto update...

Comment: Or maybe use updater4pyi-- `pip install updater4pyi`?

Comment: @Swagrim I'm not familiar with py2exe. Is it better?

Comment: Found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617997/auto-updating-a-python-executable-generated-with-pyinstaller) related to it

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, maybe yes, maybe no. Most people say pyinstaller is better than py2exe as it has many features like onefile, noupx etc. while py2exe hasn't. If you are not using any such options in pyinstaller, you can use py2exe by creating another file called setup.py and typing in:

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

setup(console=["<your filename with its extension(.py)>"])
```

This creates your executable, without any options.

Then you can use [Esky](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) to make it auto-updateable. I have no Idea of how to use esky actually, but it does work.